Typescript: Why does this simple inference fail?
function bad<T extends 'doAfter'>(instance: Record<string, any>, fnName: T) {
  switch (fnName) {
    case 'doAfter':
      break;
    default:
      const x: never = fnName;
  }

  return null;
}

function good(instance: Record<string, any>, fnName: 'doBefore' | 'doAfter') {
  switch (fnName) {
    case 'doAfter':
    case "doBefore":
      break;
    default:
      const x: never = fnName;
  }

  return fnName;
}

Typescript Playground
In the first, the const x: never trick fails. Typescript complains that T can't be assigned to never.
In the second, typescript understands. In both cases, typescript offers no additional case than the type T offers.
Of course, I can't call either function with a fnName that doesn't meet the constraint of T, unless I use as any or //ts-ignore


This is https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13215 (and also https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014). TS unfortunately can't do control flow analysis with generic type parameters, so as soon as your function becomes generic you lose the narrowing you expected. See the other q/a for more information.
